# How to display Groups's post forwarded to Teams message using Microsoft Graph API setting Korea timezone?

Tags: powershell, odata, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

While I was trying to forward the message from Groups to Teams using Graph API, from Teams's view, the message receivedDate is showing with UTC time where it should be showing with Korea timezone. 
Can anyone help me to display with correct timezone?

I already set 1)Sharepoint team site's timezone 2)User's timezone ...

request-header on graph API setting
  -> still message's receivedDate is showing with UTC timezone
[image]

> POST 
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{Groups-id}/posts/{post-id}/forward

```
{
            "comment": "comment-value",
      "toRecipients": [
            {
                  "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Test Demo",
                    "address": "channelemailaddress@apac.teams.ms"
                  }
            }
      ]
}
```

[addhours(9) would not work like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnKX5.png)

Comment: Even the original eml message's time is showing as changed from KST into UTC.

Comment: Perhaps [this blog](https://regarding365.com/set-the-default-region-and-timezone-for-microsoft-teams-sites-a3b4d98da8c1) can help you setting the Teams timezone.

Comment: @Theo Already applied and no luck ;(

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried entering the Time Zone ID `"Asia/Seoul"` instead of the displayname `"Korea Standard Time"`

Comment: @Theo Yes I also Tried, "Asia/Seoul" and "Korean Standard Time" as well